# Complex.Pow lack of precision

Tags: c#, precision, complex-numbers

Using Complex.Pow() to calculate i^2125 gives the complex result

```
(1.42553220285208E-13, 1)
```

It doesn't matter how I formulate the call to Complex.Pow() - each of the following gives the same result:

```
Complex.Pow(Complex.ImaginaryOne, 2125.0)
Complex.Pow(Complex.ImaginaryOne, new Complex(2125.0, 0))
Complex.Pow(new Complex(0.0, 1.0), new Complex(2125.0, 0))
```

I understand that double precision floating point numbers don't have infinite precision, but the real part of the base here is 0.0 - why should there be a (compounding) lack of precision for 0?  (Compounding because as the exponent increases, so does the lack of precision in the real part of the result).

And... since I know that the real part of the base is 0.0, I can just make the real part of the result 0.0 - but is that the best way to handle the generic result here?

Edit - after reading some of the comments below I did the following:

```
Complex.Pow(Complex.ImaginaryOne, 999999999)
```

and got the following result:

```
(-1.79531386009907E-07, -0.999999999999984)
```

So the real part has lost more than 3 digits of precision.  Why is this so?

Comment: Check how it is implemented http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/Complex.cs,371 So insufficient precision on the imaginary part affects the real part.

Comment: Complex.Pow() causes both the real and imaginary parts to affect the real part of the result.  Double provides 53 binary bits of precision (15 decimal digits), every calculation produces +/- 0.5 bit of round-off error.  Worst-case you can lose a decimal digit of precision for every ~3 calculations (not counting subtraction).  Count them in the code, there are 7 calculations that need rounding plus Math.E for the real part so you can lose ~3 digits worst-case.  With the imaginary part at 1.0, the result can't be more accurate then +/- 1E-12, 1.4E-13 is well within the expected precision.

Comment: @Hans Passant How do I know there are not further calculations in (e.g.) Math.Atan2 or Math.cos that require rounding and will therefore lose digits?  Where do I stop counting?

Comment: each calculation introduces some loss. The more calculations there are the more loss will be so I don't think double is sufficient for powers with large exponents. Use a big decimal type instead

Comment: Except that the Complex methods cast Decimal to Double, so there is no benefit there...

Comment: They are *intrinsics* and can be compiled to a single CPU instruction.  So no additional error is accumulated.  That is pretty obscure knowledge but it is just not that relevant, if they would cause additional round-off error then your result is still inside the expected precision.

Comment: @Hans Passant So the additional info I added is expected?  If that's so then Complex.Pow is almost not usable.  I know the exponent is large, but the loss of precision is too much.

Comment: And further to that, Complex.Pow() is just a series of computations using Math operators and functions.  If I have a perfectly ordinary, but complicated, series of computations using doubles, where each successive computation uses the results of the previous one, and in the end it involves (say) around 30 Math operators or functions that require rounding, are you suggesting I would lose 12 digits or more of precision?  Is that really so?